# Node.js with Phonegap Cordova - How to create a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, server

I'm trying to create a server for use with my Phonegap/Cordova project. I learned a fair amount in creating a local server which uses localhost, but do not understand on how to create a server where anyone who downloads my app can log into? Searched for a significant amount of time with no luck. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Cordova will be running your app on a user's mobile device. Your Phonegap app will run on the user's device and communicate with an external server. So to answer your question, your app, run by Cordova, will have a sign up form for a user to log into and that sign up form will make an ajax request to your server that will authenticate the user. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, Phonegap has a pretty bad rep. If you are going to use a hybrid framework that uses a browser wrapper, you should use Ionic. Check it out: http://ionicframework.com/